# How do I ask my users if I can mine cryptocurrency on their browser?

Tags: website-design, user-expectation, user-research, cryptocurrency

As ridiculous as this question sounds, this is the only place out of all stackexchange websites that made sense. Let's say I have a website and I intend to use the user's browser to mine. I don't want to run hidden scripts and ruin things for the user because I am such a nice guy.  How do I design a UX that asks the person to enable/disable in-browser cryptocurrency mining. Thanks for the suggestions in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first off it's nice to hear that you're a really nice guy!

I've never seen anything like this but the first thing that pops into mind is the cookie policy alert boxes you get on most websites these days.

[image]

It should be something like this but for bcoin mining.